# Как на iPhone проверить скорость WiFi соединения?

Tags: wifi

Вариант через сайт 2ip.ru отпадает, так как он отображает некорректные данные.

Comment: Вас интересуют веб-сервисы или конкретный код?

Comment: сервисы или готовые приложения/способы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лично я пользуюсь программой speed test. Она freeware c рекламой.

Answer (score 0):

Можно проверить здесь:

1. http://inet.ya.ru/
2. http://speed.yoip.ru/
3. http://speed.yorest.ru/
4. http://speedtest.pnz.ru/

1 - долго меряет, но особенно хорошо исходящую.

2,3 - можно выбрать размер файла для теста

4 - сразу результат
   без нажатия лишних кнопок!